# stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field display format of phone number in template

Tags: django

I'm trying to figure out how to display a phone number using stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field.  I have stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field[phonenumberslite] installed.  In my settings file I have:

```
PHONENUMBER_DB_FORMAT = "NATIONAL"
PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION = "US"
```

In my model I have:

```
phone_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
```

In my form I have:

```
phone_number = PhoneNumberField(max_length=25,required=False)
```

And in my template I have:

```
{{ myform.phone_number }}
```

I am able to enter a phone number in a variety of formats (831-555-5555, 831-555-5555, 831.555.5555) and it stores properly in the database as +18315555555.

But when I use the form field in a template it always displays as +18315555555. I would like it to display as either 831-555-5555 or (831) 555-5555. How do I make the phone number display in one of these formats in my template?  Is there a tag modifier?

UPDATE: As it turns out I was setting the initial value of the form field in the form **init** method and I needed to set it to as_national.  It is now being set to (831) 555-5555.

Comment: `{{ obj.phone.as_national }}`

Comment: is your question about rendering the **form field** (in a form) or about rendering the number itself outside of a form?

Comment: It is about rendering the form field in the form.  myform is the form and phone_number is defined in my form as phone_number = PhoneNumberField(max_length=25,required=False).  The text field which is used to enter the phone number shows the number but it displays it as +18315555555.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "setting the initial value of the form field in the form init method to as_national". Would you be so kind to provide the answer to your own question to help others?

Answer (score 0):

Since your form is overriding the field, you need to redefine the region. Or you can remove the explicit definition of `phone_number` in your form.

```
phone_number = PhoneNumberField(max_length=25, required=False, region="US")
```

Comment: My form is not a ModelForm, but a form.Form so I am defining all my fields myself.  I have changed phone_number to be phone_number = PhoneNumberField(max_length=25,required=False, region='US') but the template still displays the form field phone number in a text box with the number displayed as +18315555555.  I was hoping it would display it at 831-555-5555 or (831) 555-5555.  Entering a phone number in either of these formats works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a form class

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    user_id = forms.IntegerField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100,required=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(max_length=25,required=False)

    def __init__(self, userBeingEdited=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if userBeingEdited != None:
            self.initial['user_id'] = userBeingEdited.id
            self.initial['email'] = userBeingEdited.email
            if userBeingEdited.phone_number != "":
                self.initial['phone_number'] = userBeingEdited.phone_number.as_national
```

I erroneously didn't include as_national on the last line of this `__init__` method and the phone number was not being formatted.